# Umbraco relations service and slave Umbraco instances

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

This question relates to **Umbraco, Umbraco slave instances** and the **Umbraco Relation Service API**.

We currently have a site designated as a master Umbraco instance which handles all updates to content. Our intention is to set up slave instances in different regions around the world behind a traffic manager to improve site performance globally.  We've tested and this setup works fine.

As I understand it, the Umbraco slave instances with the "out of the box" slave configuration will not have their own databases, but instead poll a service on the master instance for content.

**Question**

We were planing on using the Umbraco relations API to relate multilingual content.  I understand that this incurs a hit on the database, as our slave websites will not have a database, I presume this won't work.

- Is my understanding of the situation correct?
- Can the relations API be configured to work in this situation?
- If not, is there a recommended alternate approach to managing related content in a way that will be supported by slave servers?

Thanks for any help you can provide, I'd be happy to answer any questions or provide any clarification necessary.

Comment: Hey, Would you be able to tell what exact thing you want? I've done some work on exact same environment as master and slave server with umbraco, Yes database will be only on master server and slave servers will access that data only. api should be deploy on master server. not sure what do you mean by multilingual content with api. If you can tell me exact problem i may able to solve your doubts.

Comment: Hi @RushabhMaster , firstly thanks very much for your response.  Perhaps my language isn't helpful, for "relations API", read "relations functionality of Umbraco".  

What we want is to use the Relations service in Umbraco to link content to its translated alternatives in other language branches of the website (e.g. www.site.com/en-gb/about-us would be linked to www.site.com/pt-br/sobre-nós).  This would allow us to set hreflang information and provide a language picker.

My understanding is that the relations functionality hits the database (which I assume wouldn't work)

Comment: Relations service

https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/management/services/relationservice/

Comment: Hey @Christopher Thomas, I looked at this link and seems fine to me like its using Umbraco core dll and should be fine for your environment. your problem, I can think now is that your frontend server (slave server) is not hitting the database. One very basic thing I can think of at this moment is your API URL structure, Basically, it should point to master server. have you configured your base URL to the master server? If yes then put some logs at the very first request and also look at Umbraco logs on slave servers.